# Dose attenuation decrease frequency

Tags: electromagnetism, experimental-physics, atomic-physics, nuclear-magnetic-resonance

What cause the transveres decay in nmr? From wiki I have an understanding that it has somthing to do with decoherence which is caused by spin of one atom effecting anouther.

That my basic understand, could anyone elaborate further?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spin precession rate depends on the local magnetic field strength. Nearby spins result in fluctuating magnetic "noise", which randomly disturbs the precession rate and therefore the phase of the spin precession in the atoms being sensed by nmr.  The random differences in spin phase accumulate and are referred to as decoherence.